# nested try catch is not thrown

Tags: node.js, try-catch

I am attempting to use a nested try statement within the catch statement but for some reason, when I throw the exception, it doesn't return in that try and im not understanding why. I saw other examples online that used it this same way, it seemed like at least.

```
  try {
        await page.waitForSelector('#ember1453 > section > div > div.status-message.fade-in.show > p.status-description', {
        timeout: 10000
      })
      resolve(0);
    } catch {
      console.log('Not complete');
      try {
        checkForErrors(page);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Confirm ID error code " + e);
        var FULL_LEGAL_NAME_SELECTOR = '#full_name';
        var DOB_SELECTOR = '#birthdate'
        var SSN_LAST_FOUR = '#ssn_last_four'
        var CONTINUE_ID_BUTTON = '#ember1406 > button';

        await page.type(FULL_LEGAL_NAME_SELECTOR, 'XXX');
        await page.type(DOB_SELECTOR, XXXXXXXX);
        await page.type(SSN_LAST_FOUR, 'XXXX');
        await page.click(CONTINUE_ID_BUTTON);
      }
    }
```

This is what I have in my switch statement (this is working for other try catch blocks, just not this nested one

Comment: Is the issue that errors thrown in `checkForErrors` do not get caught? Does that function return a Promise?

Comment: It throws an exception when I use this not nested. Im not using promises here, although I could, im just throwing exceptions

Comment: So the issue is indeed with an error thrown in `checkForErrors` not going into the second `catch`, is that right? (The `'Not complete'` runs, yes?)

Comment: I ended up just rewriting to a promise and it works there :)